# How to load a nodejs module in PyV8?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, jsdom

How can I load a nodejs module in PyV8?

I've read all about how great jsdom is when run with nodejs. Will I get the same dom-traversing benefits if I run v8 inside a Python app, with python "getting" the web resources, then giving the resulting html strings to the v8 instance, which has loaded jsdom internally

(or is this a nonsensical configuration for some reason I haven't thought of yet?)

Comment: and by running v8 "inside" my Python app, I'm referring to using PyV8 to create a v8 context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible as jsdom requires some node constructs which are not available under vanilla v8.  Things like require, core libraries, and the method of sandboxing a window would take a bit of work to pull out of jsdom.

You may want to take a peek at https://github.com/andreasgal/dom.js/

Comment: from the creator himself! Thanks. We've already moved over to node with jsdom anyway.